# Very simple BigQuery SQL script won't return "0" for Count rows with no results

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to make this very simple SQL script work:

```
SELECT
  DATE(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(created_utc)) date_submission,
  COUNT(*) AS num_apples_oranges_submissions
FROM
  [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2008]
WHERE
  (LOWER(body) CONTAINS ('apples')
  AND LOWER(body) CONTAINS ('oranges'))
GROUP BY
  date_submission
ORDER BY
  date_submission
```

The results look like this:

```
1   2008-01-07  3    
2   2008-01-08  1    
3   2008-01-09  2    
4   2008-01-10  3    
5   2008-01-11  2    
6   2008-01-13  2    
7   2008-01-15  2    
8   2008-01-16  3
```

As you can see, for days where there were no submissions containing both "apples" and "oranges", instead of a value of 0 being returned, the entire row is simply missing (such as on the 12th and 14th).

How can I fix this? I'm at my wits end. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below, it will return all submissions days

```
SELECT
  DATE(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(created_utc)) date_submission,
  SUM((LOWER(body) CONTAINS ('apples') AND LOWER(body) CONTAINS ('oranges'))) AS num_apples_oranges_submissions
FROM
  [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2008]
GROUP BY
  date_submission
ORDER BY
  date_submission
```

Comment: This worked, Mikhail! Thank you so much... you solved in just a few minutes what I had been searching StackExchange and Google all afternoon...